# getting data from two tables in mysql, join wouldn't work here

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get data from the database in order to create a list of checkboxes, and set them as `checked="checked"` if the specific user has already checked them last time...

So I have two tables - one is the specialties table, which has the specialty name, and specialty ID.

The other one is the user_specialties, which has a user id (uid) and specialty id (sid)...

The thing is I can't get a complete list of all the specialties, with the corresponding data from the user_specialties - and don't know what checkboxes to check...

I tried the following:

```
function genspecialties($id = 0) {
  $query =  "select * from specialties s RIGHT JOIN user_specialty us on s.id = us.sid ";
```

This query will get me the same specialty the number of times as the people have it, multiple times the same specialty for each user... not good :/

so I thought maybe:

```
$query =  "select * from specialties s RIGHT JOIN user_specialty us on s.id = us.sid where us.uid = '$id' ";
```

But this wasn't good either, as (of course) it only brought back the specialties that the user have, and skipped those which he do not....

So, maybe anyone have any idea how can I get all the specialties, and a reference if the user has it or not?
I use mysql with PHP...
thanks!
Yanipan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood correctly, this should do what you need:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT (specName, (IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM user_specialty us WHERE s.id = us.sid AND us.uid = '$id' LIMIT 1))) FROM specialities s;");
while (list($spec, $checked) = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    // Do your outputting here.
}
```

**Edit**

Per your request, I'll go ahead and explain the query. The part that's probably confusing you is this subquery:

```
(IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM user_specialty us WHERE s.id = us.sid AND us.uid = '$id' LIMIT 1))
```

The `IF EXISTS` tells MySQL to return either TRUE or FALSE if the part immediately following it 'exists' (contains a result). The `SELECT * FROM user_specialty us WHERE s.id = us.sid AND us.uid = '$id' LIMIT 1` simply tells MySQL to find up a row in `user_specialty` where `s.id = us.sid` (the speciality ID matches) and `us.uid = '$id'` (the ID is the user's).

Comment: Hi EdoDodo, and thanks for the interesting query. still having some mysql errors with it but i'll let you know if I managed to used it :)

Comment: Hi, thanks so much, it worked great ! now I just need to understand the syntax so I can use it next time :)

Comment: I've added a short explanation. Let me know if there's anything you still don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

i think you have all the tools you need.

wherever you are creating the checkboxes, simply create tehm as unchecked, then make a pass on the result set to see if any should be checked, and check only those.

Comment: Hi Randy, thank you for the quick response. I had a feeleing I could do it like that, but wanted somthing more elegant like edododo suggested - possibly in the query level... if I can make it work :) if not, i'll go on with your idea which is much easier...

Answer (score 1):

This should be what you need. The third field ist ether checked or NULL.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT s.id, s.name, (SELECT 'checked' FROM specialties AS s2 JOIN user_specialties AS us ON s2.id = us.sid WHERE uid = '$id' AND s.id = s2.id ) AS checked FROM specialties AS s;")
```

Comment: You are correct, it is exectly what I needed, worked out of the box... Thanks :)