# Join Two tables multiple times

Tags: mysql, join

I need result from two tables , where one is parent table and other is child table as well as parent table it self for sub level child entries.

if i do the sql query like:

```
   SELECT cc.collection_id, cc.title, cc.type, cc.alias as forum_alias,
           SUBSTRING(cc.description,1,200) as short_desc, 
           COUNT(b1.boardmessage_id) as total_threads,
           COUNT(b2.boardmessage_id) as total_replies 

   FROM contentcollections cc 
        JOIN boardmessages b1 ON b1.parent_id = cc.collection_id  
        JOIN boardmessages b2 ON b2.collection_id = cc.collection_id 

   WHERE cc.type=1 
         AND cc.is_active=1 
         AND b1.parent_type='collection' 
         AND b1.is_active=1 
         AND b2.parent_type IN('message','reply','reply_on_reply') 
   GROUP BY cc.collection_id 
   ORDER BY cc.created DESC;
```

it gives me the wrong out put with same number of total threads and same number of total replies.How ever if i do something like this

```
SELECT cc.collection_id, cc.title,cc.type, cc.alias as forum_alias,
       SUBSTRING(cc.description,1,200) as short_desc,
       (SELECT COUNT(boardmessage_id) 
        FROM boardmessages 
        WHERE parent_type='collection' 
              AND collection_id=cc.collection_id 
              AND is_active=1) as total_threads,
       (SELECT count(boardmessage_id) 
        FROM boardmessages
        WHERE parent_type IN('message','reply','reply_on_reply') 
              AND collection_id=cc.collection_id AND is_active=1) as total_replies 
FROM contentcollections cc
WHERE cc.type=? AND cc.is_active=? 
ORDER BY cc.created DESC
```

It gives me the correct answer.

I suspect i am using sub queries in the second option so it may slow down the performance of the page rendering.

Please suggest me for the same.Any help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Go through thsi link...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6724183/getting-data-from-two-tables-in-mysql-join-wouldnt-work-here


It might help You.

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
COUNT(b1.boardmessage_id) as total_threads,
COUNT(b2.boardmessage_id) as total_replies
```

With:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT b1.boardmessage_id) as total_threads,
COUNT(DISTINCT b2.boardmessage_id) as total_replies
```

if you only want each row to count once, instead of the default, counting all combinations.
If you have 3 rows in b1 and 5 rows in b2, you get a total of 15 rows, and both counts return that there are 15 rows, with the distinct flag you get the answers 3 and 5 instead, as its 3 distinct values in b1, and 5 distinct values in b2.